# SMDiagnostics not resolved

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an old Xamarin project which compiled OK a year or so ago, in VS2017.
Today I tried recompiling, but I am getting this error:
*Can not resolve reference: `SMDiagnostics`, referenced by `Mono.Android` > `System.Runtime.Serialization`. Please add a NuGet package or assembly reference for `SMDiagnostics`, or remove the reference to `Mono.Android`*
AFAIK I haven't changed anything in my project, although of course Windows10 will have been updated.
There are several options for Mono.android in the reference manager:

[image: reference manager]

I have tried removing the ref and re-installing a couple of them, with no improvement.
Furthwermore, I have searched for 'SMDiagnsotics' in the project and found no mention of it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Now aded a new reference to SMDiagnostics; that issue resolved  but moved on to a new error. Strange though how unchanged project source can result in multiple errors after a short break of not maintaining it.